# Реализация таблиц для футбола в MySQL

Tags: структуры-данных, kohana, mysql

Хочу реализовать турнирную таблицу чемпионатов по футболу + календарь игр. Реализовал следующие таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `tournaments` ( //таблица которая хранит названия чемпионатов + логотип
`id_tournament` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`id_logo` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_tournament`)
)

CREATE TABLE `teams` (//список команд
`id_team` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`id_tournament` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
`id_logo` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_team`)
)

CREATE TABLE `tables` ( //турнирная таблица(победы, проиграши, ничьи, мячи)
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_team` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`win` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`draw` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`loss` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`goal_s` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`goal_m` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `games` (//таблица расписание игр
`id_game` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_tournament` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', //турнир
`id_team_one` INT(5) NOT NULL, //команда хозяев 
`id_team_two` INT(5) NOT NULL, //команда гостей
`datetime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL, //время игры
`tour` INT(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL, //номер тура
`goals_one` INT(2), NULL DEFAULT NULL, //ко-во забитых голов 1-й команды, если NULL игра еще не состоялася
    `goals_two` INT(2) //  
PRIMARY KEY (`id_game`)
)
```

Хочу услышать мнения, является ли данная структура оптимальной. Как по мне так таблицу игр может лучше как то по другому сделать, к примеру разделить на две таблицы. Реализовать все хочу на Kohana :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Команда может участвовать в нескольких турнирах: кубки всеразличные. принадлежность команды к турниру определяется календарем игр. Хотя для удобства ввода можно развязочную таблицу добавить (`team_id`, `tournament_id`).
2. Турнирная таблица не нужна, данные собираются по расписанию игр.

   ```
   select id_team, 
     sum(win) as win, 
     sum(loss) as loss, 
     sum(draw) as draw, 
     sum(goals_s) as goals_s, 
     sum(goals_m) as goals_m 
   from (
   select g.id_team_one as id_team, 
     IF(g.goals_one>g.goals_two,1,0) as win,
     IF(g.goals_one<g.goals_two,1,0) as loss,
     IF(g.goals_one=g.goals_two,1,0) as draw,
     g.goals_one as goals_s,
     g.goals_two as goals_m
   from games g
   where g.`datetime` < NOW()
   union all
   select g.id_team_two, 
     IF(g.goals_one<g.goals_two,1,0) as win,
     IF(g.goals_one>g.goals_two,1,0) as loss,
     IF(g.goals_one=g.goals_two,1,0) as draw,
     g.goals_two as goals_s,
     g.goals_one as goals_m
   from games g
   where g.`datetime` < NOW()
   ) t group by id_team;
   ```

   есть другой вариант хранения календаря игр: для каждой игры генерить две записи, для каждой команды свою, тогда турнирная таблица будет проще формироваться, ну тут в принципе разница не большая. речь идет от сотнях записей, не о миллионах. разница будет не заметна.
3. состоялась или не состоялась игра лучше определять по дате или добавить спец поле, `NULL` - плохая идея.

Comment: Еще добавлю. Есть такая модная штука - лайв скоринг, который содержит фактически протокол матча. Там могут быть разные события. Начиная от голов и замен, ударов по воротам и угловым, заканчивая комментариями типа [такой трансляции](http://www.gazeta.ru/brazil2014/schedule/match/6039649.shtml). тогда к игре можно добавить подчиненную таблицу, потом по ней собирать статистику...

Comment: Составлю я к примеру календарь игр на весь турнир. Как мне узнать к-во игр, побед и тд.. к примеру для Чемпионата Украины и отдельно для Лиги Чемпионов к примеру. Получается все равно нужно поле tournament_id или еще таблица одна.

Comment: @ager32, 

> Хотя для удобства ввода можно развязочную таблицу добавить (team_id, tournament_id).

Answer (score 3):

1. Команда не может относиться к соревнованию, поскольку одна команда может участвовать в любом числе турниров (внутренний чемпионат, кубок страны, кубок лиги, Лига чемпионов, Лига Европы и тд), также как и в одном соревновании может участвовать (а точнее, не просто может, а всегда участвует) несколько команд. Отсюда следует, что отношение команда-соревнование должно выражаться как многие-ко-многим
2. Не отражена принадлежность команды к той или иной лиге (а также городу и стране, впрочем, это опционально). Не бывает "просто команд", каждый профессиональный клуб является участником той или иной лиги и  время от времени может менять одну на другую
3. Турнирная таблица не должна быть отдельной таблицей, как верно заметил [[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov), ее данные извлекаются из результатов матчей. Однако добавлю, что наличие отдельной таблицы не только бесполезно, но и потенциально вредно - возможна несогласованность данных. Например, занесли в турнирную таблицу данные о победе одной команды, а в таблицу расписаний забыли (ну или не смогли из-за возникшей ошибки). И тогда получится, что данные из одной таблицы не соответствуют данным из другой, ведь никакими ограничивающими отношениями они не связана. Более того, в случае с турнирной таблицей вам придется заносить одни и те же данные дважды - скажем, команда А выиграла у команды Б со счетом 2:0. Вам сначала придется отредактировать данные команды А в турнирной таблице, добавив ей в статистику одну игру, одну победу и 2 забитых мяча, а затем проделать по сути то же самое для команды Б, добавив ей одну игру, одно поражение и 2 пропущенных мяча. По сути двойная работа, плюс здесь тоже может возникнуть несогласованность данных уже в рамках одной таблицы (например если вы для команд А и Б ошибочно занесли разные данные).   Если хочется ее хранить в виде отдельной сущности, то сделайте View
4. В таблице расписания не стоит хранить информацию по играм - в случае, если игра еще не состоялась, у вас будут сплошные NULL из-за отсутствия данных. Логичнее вынести информацию по конкретным играм в отдельную таблицу и связать ее с турнирной таблицей внешним ключом, тем самым в ней будет содержаться лишь информация о прошедших играх
5. Сомнительным является поле tour - если ресь идет о товарищеском матче или кубке, то это понятие становится бессмысленным